# Adjust figure when using plt.gcf

Tags: image, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have a image plotted using

```
 plt.gcf()
```

and the command

```
 plt.gca().add_artist
```

I edited the axes with

```
 fig.gca(xlim=[-5,5],ylim=[-8,2])
```

The problem is that when I save the image, it gives me:

[image]

I want that in any pair of axes, I get the exact image and not a stretched image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ax = fig.gca()
ax.set_aspect('equal')
```